# Grouping by one column and finding minimum from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, aggregate-functions

I'm struggling with how I could use SQL aggregate functions and grouping to find the right record in my table. Below is a simplified example. I want to group by B and find the record with the minimum value of C. My problem being that I must either include A in the grouping or apply an aggregate function to A, none of which seem suitable.

```
A   |  B  |   C
7   |  2  |   1
4   |  2  |   2
```

These are simplified versions of the two queries I've tried.

```
select A, B, min(c)
from @Table1
group by B, A

select min(a), B, min(c)
from @Table1
group by B
```

The query would need to return this:

```
A   |  B  |   C
7   |  2  |   1
```

And ideally only one record for multiple values of C.

Comment: select max(a),min(b),min(c) from table

Comment: what is the desired output you need, in this example.

Comment: Can there be ties, i.e. two records with the same B and C? Is this wat you are referring to with "And ideally only one record for multiple values of C"? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yea apologies Thorsten I think I worded that badly, the query needs to return only one record even where there are records with the same B and C. You've touched on it in your solution and I think that will work, I'll do some testing now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Per B you want the record with the minimum C. This can be achieved with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select a, b, c
from
(
  select a, b, c, row_number() over (partition by b order by c) as rn
  from @Table1
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

If there are ties (same B, same C) one of the records is picked arbitrarily. If you want a certain one (e.g. least or greatest A), then extend the `ORDER BY` clause. If you want all best ranked records in case of a tie, use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

Should also bring your desired result:

```
SELECT mt.*
 FROM mytable mt
 INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT B, MIN(C) as C
      FROM mytable
     GROUP BY B
    ) min
ON mt.B = min.B
AND mt.C = min.C
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the records for which not exists another record with the same B and a lower C.

```
select *
from @Table1 t1
where not exists
(
  select *
  from @Table1 better
  where better.b = t1.b
    and better.c < t1.c
);
```

If there are ties (same B, same C) you will get multiple records per B. If you only want only one of them, then extend the `WHERE` clause if possible or choose another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each record with the min C you can use the query below. If you want one record per B you can use the answer Thorsten provided.

```
Declare @myTable table (A int, B int, c int)
insert into @myTable values (7,2,1),(4,2,2),(6,2,1)

select a,b,c
from(
        select *, min(c)over(partition by B) minc
        from @myTable
        ) D
where c=minC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (A int, B int, C int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (A, B, C)
VALUES
    (7, 2, 1),
    (4, 2, 2)
;
```

**Script  :**

```
Select A.A,A.B,AA.C from 

(select B,MAX(A)A from @Table1
GROUP BY B)A
INNER JOIN (
select B,MIN(C)C from @Table1
GROUP BY B)AA
ON A.B = AA.B
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is you need

```
 select max(a),min(b),min(c) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the answer for your problem like this.

select A, B,MIN(C) As a 
from Table
where B in 
          (
            SELECT Max(B)
            FROM Table
            GROUP BY B
          )